# How to do a get request with all idRefs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, http, express

I have 2 models in my project, 1 is stores and the other is products, the stores has a reference to products like this:

```
produtos: [
  { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Produto' }
]
```

and basicly at the moment i have a object like this:

```
{
  "_id": "589715a3a2030f7bc143ed89",
  "nome": "levis2",
  "email": "filipecostaa10@gmail.com1",
  "password": "1234",
  "__v": 8,
  "produtos": [
    "58971695a2030f7bc143ed8a",
    "589716d7a2030f7bc143ed8b",
    "58971742a2030f7bc143ed8c",
    "58971770a2030f7bc143ed8d",
    "589717a1a2030f7bc143ed8e",
    "58971848a2030f7bc143ed8f",
    "589718f5a2030f7bc143ed90",
    "58971937a2030f7bc143ed91"
  ],
  "descricao": "No description for this store"
}
```

the array `produtos` has a lot of ids. Those ids are reference to the products; What i need to know now is how i can do a get request to get all the products with those ids, how do i send the request?

**here is my router**

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
  Loja.find(function(err,lojas){
      if(!lojas){
        return res.status(404).json({Error:"Loja nao encontrada"});
      }
      res.send(lojas); 
  }).populate("Produto");
})
```

Comment: Try `Loja.find().populate('produtos').exec(function(err, lojas) { res.send(lojas) });`

Comment: worked friend, strange is that i already did it 1 or 2 times like i did before and worked, can you post that as response with a brief explain

Comment: Answer Updated.

Comment: gj that took me a long time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are trying to get all stores with [populated](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) products field so:

```
router
  .route('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      Loja
        .find()
        .populate('produtos')
        .exec(function(err, lojas) {
          if ( err ) {
            return handleError(err);
          }
          res.json(lojas);
        });
    });
```

Comment: i will update my answer so you can see what i am doing, it never updates all the products :/